# how do you train a neural network to determine shortest path in a 4-node graph

Tags: neural-networks, shortest-path-problem

Suppose I have the following graph:

```
        (2)           (3)
   A ---------- B ---------- D
      \          |          /
       \         |         /   
        \        |        /
         \      (1)     (3)
          (5)    |      /
           \     |     /
            \    |    /
             \   |   /
              \  |  /
               \ | /
                 C
```

The shortest distance from A to C is 3 (A --> B --> C).
There are many algorithms ([BFS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-search-or-bfs-for-a-graph/), [Dijkstra's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), etc..) that can figure this out.

I am wondering if I can train a simple neural network to come up with the shortest path shown above, given enough training data.

The idea is to train it with maybe 20 four-node graphs like the one shown above and provide it the correct shortest path.  Then test it with another 5 four-node graphs to see if it gets the right answer. Right now I'm focusing on 4-node graphs to keep things simple.

Here is what I'm thinking :

For the example graph shown above you can see there are 5 edges (AB, AC, BC, BD, CD). The weights of these edges will be fed to the input layer of the neural network.  So I think the input layer should have 5 neurons.  The output layer will have 4 neurons, each outputting a score between 0 an 1.  In the example graph above, the output would look like:

```
neuron A  = 1.0
neuron B = 0.75
neuron C = 0.50
neuron D = 0
```

So the output above indicates a path starting from highest score --> lowest score (i.e. A --> B --> C).  Since D is 0, the path does not include D.

I'm a little confused how to think about the hidden layer and what the loss function would be.  I think the loss function is essentially minimizing the distance traveled, but how do a neuron "know" what distance has already been traveled?

Would appreciate any thoughts from the community.

Comment: This can be done by Reinforcement learning AND backpropagation techniques, if the pattern is found.